# How to make this table query more efficient

Tags: sql, c#-3.0

I've added a dataset , and a table adapter to my C# project.(The dataset and tableadapter was added via DataSources box)
In this query , I get table data , then filter , then I will iterate and fill a listbox.

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();
ETPDataset.t_USR_UsersDataTable tbl = (new ETPDataset.t_USR_UsersDataTable());
ETPDatasetTableAdapters.t_USR_UsersTableAdapter tblAdap = new TestIntellisenseSql.ETPDatasetTableAdapters.t_USR_UsersTableAdapter();
tblAdap.Connection.ConnectionString = scon.ConnectionString;
tblAdap.Fill(tbl);
ETPDataset.t_USR_UsersRow[] rows2;
rows2 = (ETPDataset.t_USR_UsersRow[])tbl.Select("USR_RECORDID > 60");
foreach (ETPDataset.t_USR_UsersRow drow in rows2)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(drow.USR_UserID);
}
```

This is my problem

```
tblAdap.Fill(tbl);
```

because this line of code will fetch ALL data(problem for big tables) , how can i fix it ?
-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new method on your adapter to use a `where` clause to filter the data at the database.

Comment: There is no point to fetching all the data from database and filter it at program. Is there any problem you cant filter "USR_RECORDID > 60" at database?

Comment: Once you added the filter to the adapter, the Fill() method will take the value as a parameter, ie Fill(USR_ID)

Comment: Edit your dataset in the designer, r-click the data table and choose 'Configure'. In the query insert your parameter (@ID), click Finish.

Comment: I would not want to use stored procedure

Comment: @KeyboardMonkey Thanks a lot
This way I do not have to hard code the column names but It help me use intellisense.